# Dynamic matrix class

Tags: c++, class, matrix, dynamic

I need to construct a matrix class and assign values to it with a specific function.

Here's my code:

```
class MATRIX
{
    int row, col;
    double **p;
public:
    MATRIX(int, int);
    void Set(int, int, double);
    ~MATRIX();
};

MATRIX::MATRIX(int x, int y)
{
    row = x;
    col = y;
    p = new double*[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        p[i] = new double[y];
    }
}

void MATRIX::Set(int a, int b, double d)
{
    p[a][b] = d;
}

    MATRIX::~MATRIX()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        delete[] p[i];
    delete[] p;
}

int main()
{
    MATRIX A(2, 3); // Initializes a matrix with size 2x3
    MATRIX B(7, 4); // Initializes a matrix with size 7x4

    A.Set(1, 2, 4.7); // Sets the value of A[1][2] to 4.7
    B.Set(0, 3, 2.9); // Sets the value of B[0][3] to 2.9
}
```

I see this in the debugger when in the `Set` function:

```
this->p was 0x1110112
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What shows that error? Your debugger? What was happening when it did?

Comment: Ditch the error prone manual memory management and just use a `std::vector` (or *at least* use smart pointers - we are not in '98 any more - modern C++ is *much* better than this crud).

Comment: What's wrong with `p` being  0x1110112? What should it have been?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is C++ and this looks more like C. Maybe a good first step is to edit some of your code. I would suggest you change your C-style array for a std::array or a std::vector. It would like this in the header file:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t rows, std::size_t columns> 
class MATRIX
{
    std::array<std::array<T, columns>, rows> matrix_data;

public:
    MATRIX();
    void Set(int, int, double);
    ~MATRIX();
};
```

This uses a template class which means you have to do something like this in the main

```
MATRIX<double, 2, 3> A;
```

I dont have the time to write the whole code, but i think this will get you going! Goodluck!